# Can I use Magento as a decent CMS as well as store?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, e-commerce, opencart, webstore

Just after some advice: I need to build a webstore that has a large amount of CMS features.

I was thinking about using OpenCart in parallel with a CMS like Wordpress or ModX, but things might get a little messy. I am wondering, if Magento has the ability to provide decent CMS features.

What I would need, along side the store, is:

- a blog
- an image gallery (upload images not related to products)
- news page with individual news articles
- ability to create an infinite number of other regular pages

Would Magento be ok to use for this?

Or am I better off using a split CMS/e-store system?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Magento's CMS pages in your site but if you have a lot of them I wouldn't go that route myself - particularly if you are letting the client loose on them, I personally don't like the Magento WYSIWYG editor much and tend to disable it on all my sites and just use HTML for the CMS pages.

**Edit**

Coming back to this years later.  I still do this now, using Wordpress for the CMS content.  You can see this link for the nest way to integrate the two in my opinion;

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-integrate-wordpress-inside-of-magento/9865#9865

Comment: I've given you an upvote for the first half of your answer - as soon as you recommended Wordpress I hesitated... ;)

Comment: Ha, I don't blame you @RobbieAverill - It might not be the most efficient in terms of caching but you could always pull the content from Wordpress via json and host it on a different server.  I still use Wordpress as the CMS for content now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Magento offers static pages by default.
Blog and Image Gallery are additional plug-ins that can be found on magentoconnect. They fit to the theme you choose so everything appear in the same style.

If it really fit your need you might have to install Magento and the two plug-ins. I found those:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lazzymonks-wordpress-integration-2-61.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/i-gallery-gallery-image-free.html

But I would prefer split logic but with the same style. A good Magento developer could make this merging together on one site.